# laravel 5 : authenticate certain folders in public directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am working on an application that has some files (pdf documents etc) hosted in the public directory and therefore directly accessible by any user if they are aware of the filename.

There are a few cron jobs that read/write to this folder as well as some controller functions that manipulate it.

I am currently working on moving these files to the storage folder (where they rightly belong) and also updating the various cron/crontrollers from using this path (single config path)

In the meantime, I would like to know if there is a simple way for me to authenticate these folders (public/documents public/pdf) via the laravel auth layer so that only authenticated users can access

Regards,

Comment: I'm also interested in this. In some older project we went with this solution: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/image-accessibility-for-authenticated-users-only

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through your web server configs (Apache/nginx). You would have to make the sub-directory in your app root private in the configs and redirect requests for the sub-directory to index.php

Long story short: I would recommend the proper method of moving your private files to the storage folder. This is a pretty messy configuration